# Does Vertx 3 support CompletableFuture?

Tags: java-8, promise, vert.x, completable-future

I want to develop my application promise style using vertx and CompletableFuture fits really for this purpose but JVM uses fork/join on the background for CompletableFuture and this may break Vertx Thread Safety.

Do you have any idea or have used this feature on your project?

Comment: Have you tried (or looked at) [JavaRx](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does, here is an example http://qrman.github.io/posts/2015/08/28/callback_hell_completablefuture_ftw/

But I think JavaRx is the better solution because its supported as first class citizen by vert.x http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java/

Answer (score 3):

There is also https://github.com/cescoffier/vertx-completable-future. From the README:

> This project provides the Completable Future API but enforces the Vert.x threading model:
>
> - When using xAsync methods (without executor), the callbacks are called on the Vert.x context
> - When using non-async, it uses the caller thread. If it's a Vert.x thread the same thread is used. If not called from a Vert.x thread, it still uses the caller thread
> - When using xAsync methods with an Executor parameter, this executor is used to execute the callback (does not enforce the Vert.x thread system)

Haven't used yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

technically seen its always possible to do async operations on other threads that are not managed by Vertx and return the result to be consumed by Vertx managed thread. The key is to obtain a `Context` **before** starting the async operation using `vertx.getOrCreateContext()` and then using that to return the result when its ready.

Assuming you have a `Handler<AsyncResult<>>` of some kind, this can be a sample code:

```java
public void doAsyncThing(String someParam, String otherParam, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> resultHandler) {
    Context vertxContext = vertx.getOrCreateContext();
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = 
        someOperatinThatTriggersAsync(someParam, otherParam)
            .handleAsync((unused, throwable) -> {
                vertxContext.runOnContext(unused1 -> {
                    if (throwable == null) {
                      responseHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture());
                    } else {
                      responseHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(throwable));
                    }
                });
                return null;
          });
}
```